# Render a component on initial request in Svelte

Tags: frontend, svelte

I had created a website using Python and Jinja templates. And whenever a user makes a request, my code renders the Jinja template and produces an HTML and sends it out as a response (the serving is carried out by AWS lambda and API gateway).

My site is mostly static with multiple pages (like About, Help, which are also static with normal text). I have one page though, which is dynamic. It has one element, which fetches data from database, and query parameters comes from URL.

Considering that my site is mostly static, I was thinking to use GitHub Pages to host it, where my frontend part is written in Svelte (going by this [example](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#github-pages)). How can do it? I am thinking it should be possible, as when the user hits the site, the static page will be served and the component which relies on fetching data from database, I can have a function which makes an API call and fetches the data, the first time when page is loaded? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use SvelteKit for this with the static adapter. You can simply load the required data during `onMount` which is a function that only runs on the browser.

```js
// initially do not show anything
let data = [];

onMount(() => {
  const url = ...;
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(res => data = res);
});
```

to build the url from the query params you can use `$page.url.searchParams`.